# Include HTML in theme_pager_next $text variable?

Tags: 7, theming, paging

Is it possible to include markup in the $text variable of theme_pager_next()? I find that whatever I set the variable to gets output as a string, rather than being rendered as HTML. Here's some example code as would be found in template.php:

```
    function theme_pager_next($variables){ 
      $text = '<span>test value</span>';

      /* Remainder of function call goes here ...*/

      return $output;
    }
```

I would like be able to add an image to the pager text. I realize I could also use CSS background images, but would prefer to print markup to the page if at all  possible.

Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: I think we'll need to see the remainder of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rest of the code is the same used in [theme_pager_next()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_next/7), then it is not possible to add HTML tags to `$text`.

This is because `theme_pager_next()`, and [theme_pager_last()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_last/7) call [theme_pager_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_link/7). `theme_pager_next()`'s code is the following one.

```
if ($page_new[$element] == ($pager_total[$element] - 1)) {
  $output = theme('pager_last', array('text' => $text, 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));
}
// The next page is not the last page.
else {
  $output = theme('pager_link', array('text' => $text, 'page_new' => $page_new, 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));
}
```

`theme_pager_link()` then contains the following code.

```
$attributes['href'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => $query));
return '<a' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . check_plain($text) . '</a>';
```

As it calls `check_plain()`, if `$text` contains HTML tags, they are shown as plain text.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you should override `theme_pager_link()` with a theme function that doesn't call `check_plain()`. [filter_xss()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/filter_xss/7) could be a better function to use in this case, but remember to pass in `$allowed_tags` the list of the tags you want to allow.

As side note, when you want to alter the content of the `$variables` array a theme function gets, in Drupal 7 you can use its preprocess functions. Every theme function has preprocess functions, and in your theme that is `THEME_preprocess_pager_next()`. (Replace THEME with the short name of your theme.)